Not able to add value from feeder in Kafka Header in gatling kafka plugin
I'm trying to add value from a feeder to header in a Kafka request but not able to do so.
I'm using the plugin: https://github.com/galax-io/gatling-kafka-plugin
I initially set up feeders in a way similar to this:
scn = scn.feed(
  Iterator.continually(Map(UUID.toString -> getRandomValue(UUID, None)))
)

def getRandomValue(
      valueType: RandomValueTypes.Value,
      length: Option[Int]
  ): String = {
    valueType match {
      case UUID              => java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString
  }
}

And I build my Kafka scenario as:
case kafkaRequest : KafkaRequest =>
val kafkaRequestKey = kafkaRequest.key.getOrElse("")
val kafkaRequestBody = kafkaRequest.body
val kafkaRequestHeaders = mapToRecordHeaders(kafkaRequest.headers)
scn = scn.group(getNameWithTestId(ReportSections.KAFKA_GROUP, testId)) {
  exec(
    kafka(kafkaRequest.name).send[String, String](
      key = kafkaRequestKey,
      payload = kafkaRequestBody,
      headers = kafkaRequestHeaders
    )
  )
}

private def mapToRecordHeaders(
    headersOpt: Option[Map[String, String]]
): RecordHeaders = {
val recordHeaders = new RecordHeaders()
headersOpt.foreach { headers =>
  headers.foreach { case (key, value) =>
    recordHeaders.add(key, value.getBytes("UTF-8"))
  }
}
recordHeaders
}

The feeders work fine for kafka key and kafka body but do not work for headers as I get #{UUID} printed as it is rather than the value
I found a similar issue on another plugin, but the steps over there are also not helping me: Tinkoff/gatling-kafka-plugin#110
Can anyone help me out since I see that this plugin doesn't seem to support feeders for headers?
